# Launch android app on Oculus with VR mode

Tags: android, oculus, quest, oculusquest

I'm new to Oculus Development. I'm trying to run an app inside Oculus Quest 2. Right now the app runs in floating window inside Oculus. I want to run the app in VR mode. Can anyone please guide?

Answer (score 0):

'Normal' Android apps are only built to work on 2D screens.  For an app to work in VR, the app needs to be created with VR support, e.g. by creating it as an Oculus app using something like OpenXR or Unity.